# get element value from an array when there is a one value is same

Tags: php

I am working in php. I got one array like below.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (            
        [element_value] => priya@@@patel
        [group_id] => 13            
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (            
        [element_value] => 12-01-2016
        [group_id] => 13
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (            
        [element_value] => Lafayette
        [group_id] => 13
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [element_value] => 31
        [group_id] => 13
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [element_value] => smit@@@patel
        [group_id] => 14
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (

        [element_value] => 12-05-2015
        [group_id] => 14
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [element_value] => Houston
        [group_id] => 14
    )
  )
```

Now, I want **element_value** in sinle row whose **group_id** is same. And display this value into different row.

For example :

Name                  Date               place

priya@@@@patel         12-01-2016          Lafayette

smit@@@patel           12-05-2015          Houston

so what code should I have to write?

Comment: i want to display simple table.

Comment: I think it would be a lot easier if you would restructure your array so that everything you need is within in one object

Comment: This is what you need [A look at the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: @Nisarg have you tried anything before asking here? If so, could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: @Veve I am guessing you can ask till the cows come home, but you are not going to get an answer. I think this might be a _do it for me_ question

Comment: @RiggsFolly yup, I think the same ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
$grouped = [];
foreach ($yourArr as $part) {
   $grouped[$part->group_id][] = $part->element_value;
}
foreach ($grouped as &$group) {
  $group = implode(' ', $group);
}
var_dump($grouped);
```